# how to insert header or footer to a word document using c++ automation

Tags: c++, ms-word, automation, get-headers

I want to insert a header or footer in a word document using word automation.

```
_document ocDoc;
Sections DocSections = Sections(ocDoc.GetSections());
section firstSec = DocSections.Item( 1 );
HeaderFooter Hf = firstSec.GetHeaders();
Range MyRange = Hf.GetRange();
MyRange.SetText( L"salam" );
```

but code in part "Range MyRange = Hf.GetRange();" failed,
how can i insert header or footer in word document using c++?

below code in c# work correctly:

```cs
_document ocDoc;
oDoc.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Text = "My Header";
```

Comment: When you say it failed -- what did it do exactly? Throw an exception, crash, return NULL, something else?

Comment: This looks awesome. Im still using OLEMethods, can you provide me with some code for _document and the Section class.

Answer (score 1):

For the people who are still looking for the answer:

```
HeadersFooters Hfs = firstSec.GetHeaders();
HeaderFooter Hf = Hfs.Item(1);
Range MyRange = Hf.GetRange();
MyRange.SetText( L"salam" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Where's your C++ equivalent to

```
Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary]
```

Something like

```
Hf.GetItem(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).GetRange();
```